# Show data from a card component to a Detail Component using useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management

I´m trying to update the Detail component data whenever I select a card component.
I´m using useContext hook but I´m stuck at this point and I don´t know how to do this.
Could anybody please help?.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faHWJ.png)

context.js

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import api from "./api/players"

const APIcontext = createContext();

export function Provider({children}){

    const [players, setPlayers] = useState([]);
    const [currentPlayer, setCurrentPlayer] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {

    const fetchPlayers = async () => {

      try{
        const response = await api.get('/players');
        setPlayers(response.data)         
        
      }

      catch(err){

        if(err.response){
          console.log(err.response.data)
        }else{
           
          console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`)
        }
          
      }
    }
    
    fetchPlayers()
  },[])

  
 const UpdateDetails = () =>{
   
 
 }
    return(
        <APIcontext.Provider value={{players, currentPlayer,UpdateDetails}}>{children}</APIcontext.Provider>
    )
}



export default APIcontext;
```

---

This is the Detail Component where I want to display the data, whenever a card is selected on click.

Details.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import {useContext} from "react";
import APIcontext from "../context";

function Details() {

   const {players} = useContext(APIcontext)
  return (
    <Card  style={{width:"80%", marginRight:"20px"}}>
      <Card.Header className="text-center"><h1>Details</h1>
      </Card.Header>
      <Card.Body className="px-5">
       <h4>{players.realName}</h4>
       <h4>{players.realName}</h4>
       <h4>{players.assets}</h4>
        <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default Details;
```

---

This is the Card component that displays the data from the players. By clicking on one of them the Details component should be updated.

Card Component

```
    [enter code here
 import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import APIcontext from "../context";

function Cards({}) {
  const { players } = useContext(APIcontext);
  console.log("players", players);

  const { UpdateDetails} = useContext(APIcontext)

  return (
    <>
      {players &&
        players.map((player) => (
          <Card
            key={player.id}
            className="mt-4 mx-2"
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              width: "12rem",
              height: "9rem",
              whiteSpace: "nowrap",
              overflow: "hidden",
              textOverflow: "ellipsis",
            }}
          >
            <Card.Body onClick={UpdateDetails}>
              <Card.Title>{player.realName}</Card.Title>
              <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">
                {player.playerName}
              </Card.Subtitle>
              <Card.Text>{player.asset}</Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        ))}
    </>
  );
}

export default Cards;][2]
```

---

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Card from "./components/Card";
import Details from "./components/Details";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import Controls from "./components/Controls";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Provider } from "./context";

function App() {
  

  return (

    <div className="App">
      <Provider>
      <Container className="p-3 d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
        <Container className="p-5 d-flex flex-row mb-4 bg-light rounded-3">
          <Details />
          <Controls />
        </Container>
      </Container>

      <Container className=" mr-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3 " style={{width:"65%", float:"left", marginLeft:"10%"}}>
        <Container className="d-flex flex-row flex-justify-content-center flex-wrap mr-5 mb-4 bg-light rounded-3" >
        <Card className="mr-2"/>        
        </Container>
      </Container>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Could you share the part where you used the `Provider`? Also, how are you getting `UpdateDetails` from context when it is a part of `Provider` function?

Comment: Hey, I added the App.js file where I'm wrapping the app with the Provider. About the updateDetails...that´s the part I'm kind of stuck with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context implementation is easy, you only need to understand its flow and how to update the root values.

You have done everything right, and I believe all that is left is for you to update the `Details` component on click of the `Card` component. Here's how you could go about it.

1. In the `Card` component, where you've handled the `onClick` event:
   `<Card.Body onClick={UpdateDetails}>`, change it to: `<Card.Body onClick={() => UpdateDetails(player)}>`
   This will help us send the data of the card we want to show in the `Details` component.
2. Inside the `context` file, in the `UpdateDetails` method, collect the argument passed while calling the function and set the currentPlayer accordingly like this:
   `const UpdateDetails = (player) => setCurrentPlayer(player)`
   Here, the context will get updated and wherever you use the `currentPlayer` value will receive the new data.
3. You also need the `currentPlayer` state inside `Details` file, import it along with `players` state:
   `const {players, currentPlayer} = useContext(ApiContext)`
   Now you can use `currentPlayer.name` or any other key from the player object.

Hope this helps. Please accept this answer if it does! Thank you!

Comment: You could also use this: [Simple Context Implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-platform-6mii5o?file=/src/Details.js). Click on the names and the selected item's name will be shown as header.